# Communicate between C++ and HTML5/Javascript applications without a server

Tags: c++, html, activexobject

I have a HTML5 application that serves as a menu for particular C++ games.

As of the moment, I'm using:

```
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec(this.GAME_PATH);
```

This is from my HTML5 application to run a C++ game when a button a press. I want for both applications to have a connection and real-time data communication. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache Thrift to make the near real-time communication between C++ and JavaScript (or Node.js)
See http://thrift.apache.org/

I don't have experience using Apache Thrift with c++ but it works well fore me with JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

Qt also has support for exposing C++ objects to javascript. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html.